# Calc, formula bar too small

Tags: libreoffice-calc

How can I increase the formula bar hight, see attached image. My version is 7.4.1.2
I tried resetting my profile without success.
[image: formula bar]

Comment: It's a documented bug https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=150664

Answer (score 0):

Likewise, if you draw down the A B C D, etc..... line, you will get some extra space but it also opens up the formula bar window.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the down arrow on the far right end of the formula bar, to open the formula bar up to be about 5 lines in height) then hover the cursor below the formula bar but above the column headings, at some point vertical adjustment arrows show. I have dragged upwards to reduce the size from 5 lines, then saved the sheet; on re-opening, the reduced height has stayed where set.[Version 7.4.6.2 (x64)]

Answer (score -1):

If you click on the down arrow on the far right end of the formula bar, it opens the formula bar up to be about 5 lines in height.
But, I am not sure how to adjust the size of this expanded formula bar.